# enable select control after setting option to select previous

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, controls

I have a form with select controls, which when selecting one, should disable the corresponding one:

[image]

Try initializing a flag to false, and when executing the onChange method change it to true but it still does not work. I leave some of the code:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>AREA DE SERVICIO*</label>
                        <select (change)="cargaSelectTipoReclamo()" formControlName="areaServicio" class="form-control" placeholder="Seleccione Area de Servicio">
                            <option value="" disabled>Seleccione Área de Servicio...</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let item of arrArServ" [value]="item.arServ_IDAreaServicio">
                                {{ item.arServ_nombre }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label>RECLAMO*</label>
                        <select [disabled]="boTipRec === true" id="ddlReclamo" (change)="selectTipoReclamo()" formControlName="tipoReclamo" [(ngModel)]="TipoReclamoID" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" disabled>Seleccione Reclamo</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let item of arrTipRec" [value]="item.tipRec_IDTipoReclamo">
                                {{ item.tipRec_nombre }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
boTipRec = false;
  cargaSelectTipoReclamo() {
try {
  this.objIDArServ = {
    tipRec_IDArServ: this.frmGenerar.areaServicio.value
  };

  this.ddlService.selectTipoReclamo(this.objIDArServ).subscribe(data => {
    this.arrTipRec = JSON.parse(data);
    this.arServ = this.arrArServ.filter(x => x.arServ_IDAreaServicio === +this.frmGenerar.areaServicio.value)[0];

    this.selectTipoReclamo();
  });

  if (this.objReclamo === null) {
    this.frmGenerar.tipoReclamo.setValue('');
    this.boTipRec = true;
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, as long as it actually goes into your if clause.
Are you sure that `this.objReclamo` really is `null` ?

Here is a simple example with a change event shows how it works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pucc3q